# Parallax, javascript with SVGs? Is that right?

Tags: javascript, svg, parallax, jquery-svg

I have seen this type of page before (Link Below), I know part of it is parallax, the other part blows my mind. The dynamic information is drawn on screen in response to the user hovering over elements on the screen. I have tried finding documentation on this, but I don't know what it is called so my searches turn up empty. I suspect SVG's are used in concert with Javascript. Does anyone know what is behind this web sorcery?

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/06/05/upshot/how-the-recession-reshaped-the-economy-in-255-charts.html?smid=fb-share&_r=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [**d3.js**](http://d3js.org/)

It is excellent for creating and manipulating svg graphics based on data and user interactions.

Its creator, Mike Bostock, works at nytimes.